# NodeJS: dependency from different custom modules

Tags: javascript, node.js

i'd like to find the best way to use dependencies among different modules. In my case, i have:

index.js (the launcher)
expiration.js (first module)
signal.js (second module)

```
expiration.js
function ExpirationsManager()
{
    //Here i must call SignalManager. What's the best way?
    SignalsManager.foo();
}

signal.js
function SignalsManager()
{
    //And here i must call ExpirationManager
    ExpirationManager.bar();
}
```

Actually, i'm instantiating these 'classes' and then do dependency injection in index.js, but i'd like to find the best solution.

Any ideas? 
Thanks

Comment: "Best" meaning what? What specific issue are you facing? What's wrong with how you're doing it now (DI from index, although it doesn't look like it)?

Comment: In the example i'm not using DI. What i mean is: is this the best way to use a module inside another or is there a better way without DI but maybe with global variables or similar?

Comment: Is there more to this question beyond just `require()` in the modules that you need within any given module?

Comment: It's another solution, but if i have not two but twenty dependencies, do a require inside each module could be problematic. I know it's another solution, i'm trying to figure out wich is the best one with a lot of modules